# Cassandra and Titan Graph connection failed

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, titan

I am using datastax community server `1.2.13` and `Titan 0.4.2`. If I use following command

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
==>titangraph[cassandrathrift:127.0.0.1]
```

Its not showing any error but when I use following in my java code:

```
Configuration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
conf.setProperty("storage.backend","cassandra");
conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1");
conf.setProperty("storage.port","9160");
TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open(conf);
```

It show following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.instantiate(Backend.java:347)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:367)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:311)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:121)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1163)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:75)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:40)
    at newpackage.TitanTest.main(TitanTest.java:24)
```

If i use `conf.setProperty("storage.backend","cassandrathrift");`

It show :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.instantiate(Backend.java:347)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:367)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:311)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:121)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1163)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:75)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:40)
    at newpackage.TitanTest.main(TitanTest.java:24)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The error makes me think you haven't downloaded the correct packaging of Titan.  If you didn't download this one [titan-all-0.4.2.zip](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/titan-all-0.4.2.zip) perhaps you should try that.

Comment: I downloaded `titan-server-0.4.2` and compiled in ubantu

Comment: Titan Server is a pre-packaged system that runs Rexster and Cassandra in two different JVMs.  That said, I would have expected all the Cassandra libs to be present such that you could use it the way you are trying to reference it.  It makes me wonder if something didn't "compile" correctly, though I'm not sure why you need to compile anything at all as downloading the zip already has everything built and ready to go.  I suggest downloading the pre-compiled version I referenced (or the pre-packaged Titan Server zip) and trying that.

Comment: if i use `titan-all` it says incompatible version about cassandra i hv tried with datastax community server 1.2.13,1.2.8.

Comment: Do you have the exact error message regarding "incompatible version"?

Comment: So here is the thing, I am using `datastax community server 1.2.13` and `titan-all-0.4.2`. If run `g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')` it gives `titangraph[cassandrathrift:127.0.0.1]` on gremlin console but if i run 'TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("/home/manish/Softwares/titan-all-0.4.2/conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties");` in java code it gives `Could not find implementation class: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager`. I am using `titan-core-0.4.2`

Comment: Sounds like you just have a dependency problem with your project for the java code?  I saw you also posted your question in the mailing list.  I think Daniel is right-on. You need to double check your dependencies for your project...something is missing?  Is your project maven-based?

Comment: yes its maven based.but elase dependency needed except `titan-core-0.4.2`

Comment: Its done...i was missing `titan-cassandra` and `titan-all` jars in my application

Comment: Hey guys, I see a similar problem but only when I try to enable SSL connections with cassandra as the backend. I'm using Titan 0.5 and do not see any jar file called titan-all in the release zip. Is there a different jar file that I might be missing ? Thanks in advance..